# Got a Bad Status Line

Tags: support, api-v2.2, python, associated

Since about 10 AM US-CDT on August 8, 2015, I've been getting

```
('http protocol error', 0, 'got a bad status line', None)
```

on a [/users/{ids}/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users) query after several successful such queries executed in a `page=` loop. This is after more than a year of running mostly successfully.

The message above is from `urllib` in Python 2.6.6. Switching to `urllib2` gives me `BadStatusLine('',)`. Null strings, zeroes and Nones don't tell me much.

I'm not receiving a backoff flag. All the successful queries performed in the loop prior to the error receive HTTP 200 responses. The only thing I receive at the time of the error (via Wireshark) is a TCP `FIN`.

I'm afraid I don't know how to see this "bad status line" or do further troubleshooting.

Comment: If you are sure that the same code works on other sites, tag this Q as a [bug] -- ***after*** editing-in an MCVE.  ... Otherwise, consider asking a question on [so] and include an MCVE. ... Use *Wireshark*, or similar, to see the actual `GET` and response.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect some new throttling kicked in on Saturday. When I slightly increased the delay between `page=` queries, the problem went away.

Comment: In that case, the code probably wasn't handling status and backoff flags correctly in the first place.  Still need that MCVE.

Comment: @BrockAdams: I had done as you suggested and used Wireshark. There was no backoff message (which my code handles) and there was no HTTP response code (after receiving a bunch of 200s during each run) to handle. I think it's the silent failure that is SE's response when it believes you're being abusive. It hadn't found my pace to be abusive for the previous 16 months so I believe there has been an unannounced change on SE's part. I'll add silent-failure detection so that it waits and tries again. No MCVE will be forthcoming, I'm afraid, since I don't have time to do the "M" part. Sorry. ...

Comment: ... I was hoping that an SE person would repond to my [tag:support] tag and give an official response regarding changes in throttling.

Comment: Official SE response is [pretty nonexistent these days here on Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/users/2/kevin-montrose?tab=activity). ... Also, I have not noticed any change in throttling. My apps typically use small bursts of requests at about 2 per second. They still receive the backoff flag before any other failure. ... It may be that it's just you. But we'll never know without a proper question or unless an SE dev comes in from the cold (which seems unlikely)